# CakePHP3.4: How to send a json object response?

Tags: cakephp-3.4

I try to migrate to 3.4 and I have a problem to send a json object.
Up to 3.3, I used the following code:

```
$jsonSites = json_encode([
    'reqLocation' => [
        'latitude' => $latitude,
        'longitude' => $longitude
    ],
    'sites' => $sitesList,
    'discoveryBooks' => $discoveryBooksList,
    'deleteSites' => !empty($inDeviceSites) ? [$inDeviceSites] : [],
    'deleteBooks' => !empty($inDeviceBooks) ? [$inDeviceBooks] : []
]);

$this->response->type('application/json');
$this->response->body($jsonSites);
```

And my client received such kind of object:

```
{
  "reqLocation": {
    "latitude": 48.080563,
    "longitude": 4.4649
  },
  "sites": [
    {
      "id": 5076,
      "name": "...",
      "modified": "2017-01-28T03:03:23+00:00",
      "directory_name": "fr/26/26120_56cc30ea4d907",
      "type": "portail",
      "longitude": 7.031953,
      "latitude": 47.939468,
      "image_0": "jpg",
      "picto_color": "#FFDDDDDD",
      "agthemes": [],
      "distance": 131.29188575851,
      "category": 1281,
      "category_name": "Jardin",
      "sitecategories": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "code": 1281,
          "name_fr": "Jardin",
          "_joinData": {
            "id": 1876,
            "site_id": 5076,
            "site_category_id": 10,
            "authorized": true
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 33,
          "code": 1283,
          "name_fr": "Jardin botanique",
          "_joinData": {
            "id": 5693,
            "site_id": 5076,
            "site_category_id": 33,
            "authorized": true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
  "discoveryBooks": [],
  "deleteSites": [],
  "deleteBooks": []
}
```

So now I just replaced the deprecated Response methods like that:

**EDIT:** Of course I return the response object but that cannot work like done here!

```
$this->response->withType('application/json');
$this->response->withStringBody($jsonSites);
return $this->response;
```

But now my client doesn't receive anything. I also tried with postman, nothing!

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the migration guide, the new reponse methods follow the PSR-7 immutability pattern.

> **Request & Response Deprecations**
>
> The bulk of deprecations for 3.4 are in the `Request` and `Response`
>   objects. The existing methods that modify objects in-place are now
>   deprecated, and superseded by methods that follow the immutable object
>   patterns described in the PSR-7 standard.

**[Cookbook > 3.x Migration Guide > 3.4 Migration Guide > Request & Response Deprecations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-4-migration-guide.html#request-response-deprecations)**

> **Adopting Immutable Responses**
>
> Before you migrate your code to use the new response methods you
>   should be aware of the conceptual differences the new methods have.
>   The immutable methods are generally indicated using a with prefix. For
>   example, `withLocation()`. Because these methods operate in an immutable
>   context, they return new instances which you need to assign to
>   variables or properties. If you had controller code that looked like:
>
> ```
> $response = $this->response;
> $response->location('/login')
> $response->header('X-something', 'a value');
> ```
>
> If you were to simply find & replace method names your code would break.
>   Instead you must now use code that looks like:
>
> ```
> $this->response = $this->response
>     ->withLocation('/login')
>     ->withHeader('X-something', 'a value');
> ```
>
> There are a few key differences:
>
> The result of your changes is re-assigned to `$this->response`. This is
>   critical to preserving the intent of the above code. The setter
>   methods can all be chained together. This allows you to skip storing
>   all the intermediate objects.

**[Cookbook > 3.x Migration Guide > 3.4 Migration Guide > Adopting Immutable Responses](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-4-migration-guide.html#adopting-immutable-responses)**

Long story short, in your case you must return the new request object created by the immutable methods:

```
return $this->response
    ->withType('application/json');
    ->withStringBody($jsonSites);
```

If you wouldn't return a response object, then you'd need to reassign the new reponse to `$this->response` as mentioned in the above quote.