# How do you send a JSON response in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to produce a JSON response. I've tried the following in my Controller methods:

```
public function removeFilter($id = null)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['result' => 'filter_removed']);
}
```

Then following instructions at [CakePHP3.4: How to send a json object response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184833/cakephp3-4-how-to-send-a-json-object-response) I also tried:

```
public function removeFilter($id = null)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    return $this->response
    ->withType('application/json')
    ->withStringBody(['result' => 'filter_removed']);
}
```

Both of these give a Response Headers of `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. There is no template associated with this Controller method, which is why `autoRender = false`.

What's going wrong here?

CakePHP 3.5.13

Comment: The easiest and cleanest way is to use .json extension in your URL. See code behind [this sandbox example](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/simple).

Comment: 2022, CakePHP 3 and 4: [Try the built-in `RequestHandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51859677/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this. `withStringBody` accepts a string only.

```
// If you want a json response
return $this->response->withType('application/json')
    ->withStringBody(json_encode(['result' => 'filter_removed']));
```

CakePHP [More Info](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-the-body)

Comment: What is `$response`?? That's not defined so that won't work.

Comment: It will be an object of Cake\Http\Response. I have edited my answer.